# ERROR LA SUBCONSULTA DEVUELVE MAS DE UN VALOR

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola necesito ayuda con este tema, en el trabajo me han dejado un proyecto, para ingresar usuarios a través de un archivo excel y que al seleccionar un usuario ya registrado en la base de datos todos sus permisos pasen a los nuevos usuarios, mi problema es cuando quiero duplicar los permisos de ese usuario en otra tabla, no sé si me entiendan, aquí esta la consulta que he usado:

```
INSERT INTO tabla1 /*tabla*/ 
            (wgru_id, 
             wusr_id, 
             wcli_cod, 
             wclte_id, 
             wcli_fecha, 
             wcli_default)/*campos a los que insertare*/ 
SELECT wgru_id, 
       (SELECT TOP (@cantidad_filas) wusr_id 
        FROM   tabla2 
        ORDER  BY wusr_id DESC), 
       /*estos son los id que quiero recuperar de la otra tabla*/ 
       wcli_cod, 
       wclte_id, 
       Getdate(), 
       wcli_default 
FROM   tabla1 
WHERE  wusr_id = @usuario_seleccionado
```

En esta consulta quiero hacer uno o varios duplicados de un registro solo cambiando el campo wusr_id, los duplicados dependen de los nuevos registros que he insertado, necesito sacar todos los ID (wusr_id) y hacer la consulta.

Me devuelve el siguiente error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Mant_spDuplicarRegistros_wusuario_cliente, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 69]
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, soy nueva en esto de las preguntas en linea, SALUDOS.

Comment: solo usa un GROUP BY wusr_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad no estoy seguro de entender la pregunta...

Pero bueno creo que necesitarías esto,

```
    INSERT INTO tabla1 /*tabla*/ 
                (wgru_id, 
                 wusr_id, 
                 wcli_cod, 
                 wclte_id, 
                 wcli_fecha, 
                 wcli_default)/*campos a los que insertare*/ 
    SELECT wgru_id, 
           wusr_id, 
           /*estos son los id que quiero recuperar de la otra tabla*/ 
           wcli_cod, 
           wclte_id, 
           Getdate(), 
           wcli_default 
    FROM   tabla1,(SELECT TOP (@cantidad_filas) wusr_id 
            FROM   tabla2 
            ORDER  BY wusr_id DESC) 
    WHERE  wusr_id = @usuario_seleccionado
```

Prueba a ver si hace lo que pides... caso contrario explica nuevamente lo que necesitas a ver si a la segunda entiendo jeje

Comment: No no sale con eso, pero gracias de igual manera, ya lo arregle :)
 Lo hice con un cursor, el cual recorre todas las filas

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre hacerlo, se que no fue entendible, yo tampoco lo entendi a la primera, gracias de todas maneras.
Este es un cursor el que consiste en recorrer todas las filas de mi tabla.

`create procedure Mant_spIngresarRegistro_wusuario_cliente
(
    @filas int,
    @id_seleccionado int
)
as
begin
declare @usr_id smallint 
declare cursor1 cursor global
for select TOP (@filas) wusr_id from dbo.WUSUARIO order by wusr_id desc
open cursor1
fetch cursor1 into @usr_id
while(@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
insert into dbo.wusuario_cliente /tabla/
    (wgru_id,wusr_id,wcli_cod,wclte_id,wcli_fecha,wcli_default)/campos a los que insertare/
    select wgru_id ,
    @usr_id,
    wcli_cod,wclte_id,GETDATE(),wcli_default 
    from dbo.wusuario_cliente 
    where wusr_id=@id_seleccionado
fetch cursor1 into @usr_id
end
close cursor1
deallocate cursor1
end`